# Can not connect to internet in 13.10

Tags: wireless, internet, 13.10

I just upgraded to ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04. Since then I haven't been able to connect to the internet. I can see the wireless networks in my area, but when I click on mine it won't connect. When I plug my laptop directly into my ethernet it still won't connect. Any one have any ideas how to resolve this?

Ethernet Controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)

Network Controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

If you need any more info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer and login.
Check if Enable NetWorking and Enable Wifi is checked (two options is in that menu).

Comment: Tried all of those already. Restarting did nothing. Both boxes are checked. I can see my wifi network but when I click it it shows the icon like it's connecting and then a notification pops up that says "Disconnected - you are now offline" but it never actually seems to connect.

Comment: Try Wired Connection. Wifi is not stable.

Comment: Tried that as well, my laptop doesn't even seem to recognize that it's connected to the modem.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Check your connection from Windows to determine the error. If you can connect to the internet from Windows, source of the error is your Ubuntu, maybe network driver for linux or a bug of Ubuntu 13.10.
I want the screenshot.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want a screenshot of. I am on my windows 8.1 pc which doesn't have wireless capabilities. It is plugged directly into the modem. My wifi is working fine on my iPhone though.

Comment: From the information you provided, you can connect to the internet from windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.04. And after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, error occurred. Maybe your laptop model is very old (seldom), but try the recovery mode (Advanced option for Ubuntu on boot menu), or anther desktop environment. My last solution is wait for new update or you can backup your data and re-install Ubuntu 13.04 because there are many bug in Ubuntu 13.10 at this time.

Comment: I know it is definitely something to do with the upgrade. My laptop is practically brand new, although a fairly cheap model. http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834257225CVF
I swapped the windows in that laptop with ubuntu and put windows on my pc. I will wait for a little while and see if I can find a resolution, if not I will go back to 13.04. Thanks for your help.